# Remote VS Code without scp

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I have a question on installing vs-code server on a remote machine without scp. I have no root priveleges on the remote. Also scp is not available on remote machine. So connection freezes on message "Setting up SSH Host $hostname: Copying VS Code Server to host with scp".

I tried to transfer .vscode-server from another remote machine that connects without problems to target remote machine but in this case the message is

> Acquiring lock on /home/username/.vscode-server/bin/5235c6bb189b60b01b1f4906"

May be the problem is in commitId 5235c6bb189b60b01b1f4906?

May be there is some solution to install the server on a remote machine in the reight way that do not leed to Acquiring lock problems?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not specific to the commit, but rooted in the problem that VSCode still can't use SCP to create lock files (or any files for that matter).

So, fix that (probably takes an email to an admin. Disabling SCP and SFTP has zero security advantage, because an attacker can do the very same thing with raw remote shell – just normal users have a harder time, as you notice). Your VS Code depends on it.

Worst case, if necessary, you can copy over your own SSH server, and matching configuration that runs as your regular user, uses a non-privileged port (instead of 22) and *has* SCP enabled, start it manually via the regular SSH connection, and use your remote machine's "official" ssh server only as *jumphost* to get to your "private" SSH server.

In short, something like

```bash
 /usr/sbin/sshd -h ~/some_key_you_generated -f /dev/null -e -D -p 9999 
#^            ^  ^ ^                      ^  ^ ^       ^  ^  ^  ^ ^  ^
#\……………….……………/  | \………………………….……………………………/  |  \…….………/  |  |  | \.…/
#       |        |            |              |     |      |  |  |  |
#Need to run     |  You'll have to generate  |   Was too  |  |  \  /
#openSSHd with   |    a valid SSH keypair.   |   lazy to  |  |   \/
#full path,else  |     But it's the same     |   write a  |  |  Use port 9999
#it refuses to   |    `ssh-keygen` invo-     |   config.  |  |  (needs to be
#run             |  cation as for genera-    |   Use de-  |  |  > 1024, for un-
#                |     ting user keys.       |   faults.  |  |    privileged
#  Specify your own                          |            |  |      users)
#     host key                       Specify your own     |  Don't fork
#                                       config file       |  into back-
#                                                         |  ground
#                                                         |  
#                                               Error messages go to 
#                                                standard output in-
#                                                stead of system log
#                                               (which we can't write,
#                                                      anyways)
```

might do

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! But my ssh command allready uses a jumping host. This gets to messy for me to understand. The command is 
 ssh -i key.pem -p 3307 -t username@jumpinghost ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@host

Comment: so, add another jumphost. No magic involved.